# Spidev read/write audio codec register

Tags: linux

I am using TI816X custom platform. There is a new SPI based audio codec (ROHM BU76312) device on my platform. I cannot find Linux driver of this codec. Thus, I want to write userspace SPI driver to control this audio codec.

I had created /dev/spidev1.2 node in kernel. But I don't know how to use spidev read/write to control this audio codec. This photo list some register of this audio codec: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27415803/photo/rohm_bu76312.jpg

If I want to write 00H/01H register, then read it back, how can I do?

This is my test program, but I don't know how to write register read/write program to control this audio codec based on spidev read/write function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE(array) sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])
static const char *spidev = "/dev/spidev1.2";
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i,fd;
    fd = open(spidev, O_RDWR);
    #if 0
    if (write(fd, wr_buf, ARRAY_SIZE(wr_buf)) != ARRAY_SIZE(wr_buf))
        perror("Write Error");
    #endif
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, which mode should I use for this SPI based audio codec? 
.mode= SPI_MODE_0 or SPI_MODE_3?

```
struct spi_board_info __initdata ti816x_spi_slave_info[] = {
.modalias   = "spidev",
.irq        = -1,
.max_speed_hz   = 7500000,
.bus_num    = 1,
.chip_select    = 2,
//.mode = SPI_MODE_3, //??
//.mode = SPI_MODE_0, //??
}
```